# 12 V 3.8 A water pump to 12 V 625CCA battery

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, 12v

Wanting to use car battery to power pump. Pump says it's 12 V 3.8 A, uses a 8 A fuse. Trying to sort out possible solar input needed to run pump but the numbers don't make sense. What size solar panel would provide enough power?

Comment: One that provided 12V at 3.8A?

Comment: Can the battery alone run the pump?  How often - and for how long - does the pump need to run?

Comment: How many hours of sunshine do you get per day? What power is available for each of those hours?

Comment: We're missing an awful lot of data. What part of the country? How can the solar panels be positioned? How often does the pump need to run? If you figure the pump draws 50W, you'll probably be okay.

Answer (score 1):

A Solar panel of 12V and 3.8Amps. That 8A of the fuse is to avoid break in the rush. Some motors have a high start current. Can be up to 7x the nominal current. However, I do not recommend you do it. Because in low light, the pump can stop and break. It's a good ideia if you use both. The solar panel and the battery.